# send back a variable with before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok i am trying to create a before_save that checks to see that fields change and return them in a variable like this

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) 
  send_email_update(@user)
  logger.info @changed
```

In the model i have a before save

```
 before_save :check_changes

 def check_changes
   @changed = self.changed
 end
```

Is there a way to do this in any way...basically sending back a variable with the changed fields or if there is a suggestion on how to tackle something like this

Answer (score 1):

Use [ActiveModel::Dirty.previous_changes()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes)

```
params[:user] = { 'name' => 'Bob' }
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) 
  send_email_update(@user)
  logger.info @user.previous_changes  # => { 'name' => ['Bill', 'Bob'] }
```